# Ansible to Conditionally Prompt for a Variable?

Tags: variables, ansible

I would like to be able to prompt for my super secure password variable if it is not already in the environment variables. (I'm thinking that I might not want to put the definition into .bash_profile or one of the other spots.)

This is not working. It always prompts me.

```
vars:
  THISUSER: "{{ lookup('env','LOGNAME') }}"
  SSHPWD:   "{{ lookup('env','MY_PWD') }}"

vars_prompt:
  - name: "release_version"
    prompt: "Product release version"
    default: "1.0"
    when: SSHPWD == null
```

**NOTE:** I'm on a Mac, but I'd like for any solutions to be platform-independent.

Comment: @AnnTheAgile When you hardcode the above variable (SSHPWD) to some dummy / actual value, did the above piece of code work for you, i.e. for NOT prompting you at all? My understanding is, it'll alway prompt you no matter whether SSHPWD was set to `null` or was set to a valid value (if hardcoded to some value instead of using/depending upon an ENV variable).

Answer (score 50, accepted):

According to the replies from the [devs](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/ansible-devel/SMyae011_Rc/Y-_sFuMQTCoJ) and a quick test I've done with the latest version, the `vars_prompt` is run *before* "GATHERING FACTS". This means that the env var `SSHPWD` is always `null` at the time of your check with `when`.

Unfortunately it seems there is no way of allowing the `vars_prompt` statement at task level.

Michael DeHaan's reasoning for this is that allowing prompts at the task-level would open up the doors to roles asking a lot of questions.  This would make using Ansible Galaxy roles which do this difficult:

> There's been a decided emphasis in automation in Ansible and asking questions at task level is not something we really want to do.
>
> However, you can still ask vars_prompt questions at play level and use those variables throughout tasks.   You just can't ask questions in roles.
>
> And really, that's what I would like to enforce -- if a lot of Galaxy roles start asking questions, I can see that being annoying :)

Comment: good explanation for the ordering of GATHERING FACTS vs vars_prompt part.

Answer (score 36):

I might be late to the party but a quick way to avoid `vars_prompt` is to disable the `interactive mode` by doing that simple trick:

```
echo -n | ansible-playbook -e MyVar=blih site.yaml
```

This add no control over which vars_prompt to avoid but coupled with `default: "my_default"` it can be used in a script.

Full example here:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars_prompt:
    - prompt: Enter blah value
    - default: "{{ my_blah }}"
    - name: blah
```

`echo -n | ansible-playbook -e my_blah=blih site.yaml`

**EDIT:**

I've found that using the `pause` module and the `prompt` argument was doing what I wanted:

```
---
- pause:
      prompt: "Sudo password for localhost "
  when: ( env == 'local' ) and
      ( inventory_hostname == "localhost" ) and
      ( hostvars["localhost"]["ansible_become_password"] is not defined )
  register: sudo_password
  no_log: true
  tags:
       - always
```

Answer (score 9):

Based on [tehmoon's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38905217/1961303) answer with some modifications I did it that way:

```
- hosts:
    - hostA
  become: yes
  pre_tasks:
    - pause:
        prompt: "Give your username"
      register: prompt
      no_log: yes
      run_once: yes
    - set_fact:
        username: "{{prompt.user_input}}"
      no_log: yes
      run_once: yes
    - pause:
        prompt: "Give your password"
        echo: no
      register: prompt
      no_log: yes
      run_once: yes
    - set_fact:
        password: "{{prompt.user_input}}"
      no_log: yes
      run_once: yes
  tags: [my_role_using_user_pass]
  roles:
    - role: my_role_using_user_pass
```

Comment: Thanks! I use tag and this works for me without 2 last lines (roles: and - role:)

Answer (score 4):

This is indeed not possible by default in Ansible. I understand the reasoning behind not allowing it, yet I think it *can* be appropriate in some contexts. I've been writing an AWS EC2 deploy script, using the blue/green deploy system, and at some point in the role I need to ask the user if a rollback needs to be done if something has gone awry. As said, there is no way to do this (conditionally and/or non-fugly).

So I wrote a very simple Ansible (2.x) action plugin, based on the pause action from the standard library. It a bit spartan in that it only accepts a single key press, but it might be of use. You can find it in a [Github gist here](https://gist.github.com/confiks/6d7b0ee3e137df01b758). You need to copy the whole Gist file to the [`action_plugins`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/developing_plugins.html#distributing-plugins) directory of your playbook directory. See the documentation in the file.

Comment: Pleae include the relevant part of your link in your answer. GitHub depositories may change at any time. Thanks.

Comment: The whole file is the relevant part. It's a module than needs to be included wholly to add extra functionality to Ansible. I added a bit more documentation to the anwer. If you mean 'relevant git commit': if I find a bug tomorrow I want future visitors to see the newer version.

Answer (score 3):

As can be seen in the [source code](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/9694d60af5e9cde7aa684e9795b79f9fbb928ce5/lib/ansible/executor/playbook_executor.py#L105), the `when` keyword isn't implemented for `vars_prompt` (and in fact never was). The same was mentioned in this Github [comment](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/19777).

The only way in which `vars_prompt` is currently conditional is that it only prompts when the variable (defined in `name`) is already defined (using the command-line `extra_vars` argument).

Answer (score 2):

This works for me (2.3) .. do two bits in the one file.
This allows me to consruct a tmp vars file when running the playbook via jenkins.. but also allow prompting on the command line

And you get to do it with only the one var used

```
---
- name: first bit                                    
  hosts:                            all
  connection:                       local            
  tasks: 
  - set_fact:                                  
      favColour:                   "{{ favColour }}" 
    when: favColour is defined

- name: second bit                                    
  hosts:                            all
  connection:                       local            
  vars_prompt:
    favColour: 
      prompt:                       "Whats ya favorite colour: "
    when: favColour is not defined

  tasks:
    - debug:                        msg="{{favColour}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @tehmoon's answer, this is what worked for me with ansible-core 2.14:

```yaml
  tasks:
    - name: Prompt SSH password if necessary
      when: ansible_password is undefined
      block:
        - name: Conditionally prompt for ssh/sudo password
          ansible.builtin.pause:
            prompt: "Password for {{ ansible_user_id }}@{{ ansible_host }}"
            echo: false
          register: password_prompt
          no_log: true

        - name: Set ansible_password
          ansible.builtin.set_fact:
            ansible_password: "{{ password_prompt.user_input }}"
          no_log: true

    - name: Set ansible_become_password
      ansible.builtin.set_fact:
        ansible_become_password: "{{ ansible_password }}"
      no_log: true
      when: ansible_become_password is undefined
```