# Ansible - when conditional not working for vars_prompt at playbook level

Tags: variables, ansible, prompt, ansible-2.x

ansible 2.1.2.0

I have a situation here for which I'm trying to check with you all to see if the solution is even possible with Ansible `vars_prompt` feature and `when` conditional.

Ansible has this feature called: [vars_prompt](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_prompts.html) and I want to club this with the [when](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_conditionals.html#the-when-statement) conditional (`when: ...` which we generally use in tasks at task or playbook level actions)

**PS:** My question is **different than this post**: [Ansible to Conditionally Prompt for a Variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25466675/ansible-to-conditionally-prompt-for-a-variable) i.e. my `vars:` variables are not dependent upon any machine's OS ENV variables, in my case, I just have a simple hardcoded value for `vars:` variables. I'm also running the when condition at the main playbook level (and not at the task's level).

What I'm trying to do is to prompt a user for entering a variable value, only if at command line, the user has called the `ansible-playbook install_tool.yml ... ...` with `--extra-vars "install_tool=true"`

In **workspace/ansible**/install_tool.yml I have:

```
- hosts: all
  become: true
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    instance: test
    #install_tool: false
    company_api_url: DUMMY_INVALID_URL

  vars_prompt:
    - name: "company_api_url"
      prompt: "Enter Company API URL: "
      default: "https://{{ instance }}.company.com"
      private: no
      when: install_tool == "true" and company_api_url == "DUMMY_INVALID_URL"
      # or
      #when: ( "{{ install_tool }}" == "true" and "{{ company_api_url }}" == "DUMMY_INVALID_URL" )

  pre_tasks:
    - debug: msg="install_tool = {{ install_tool }} and instance = {{ instance }}" 
      when: install_tool == "true"
```

**My question:**
How can I get the above conditional prompt working (with a valid substituted `default` value for a prompt variable) **and** also *SKIP* to prompt a user altogether depending upon the value of `install_tool` variable?

**My understanding:**
In top level playbook file (*install_tool.yml*), I'm defining a variable `instance` with value as `test`. Why the `default` value for the vars_prompt section did NOT pick `test` and substituted its value when it's defined at the playbook level (--OR what if a user is passing `instance` variable at command line for **ex:** `--extra-vars "instance=qa"`? In that case, I would want the default value as `[https://qa.company.com]`, how can I do that)? I don't see any errors while running it for any syntax.

I'm getting the following output (but I was expecting a substituted URL value like: `[https://test.company.com]`) **and** it's still prompting even when `install_tool` was set or passed at command line as `false`:

Running:

```
$ ansible-playbook -i "localhost," --connection=local install_tool.yml --extra-vars "install_tool=false instance=qa"
```

or

```
$ ansible-playbook -i inventory -l localhost install_tool.yml --extra-vars "install_tool=false"
...
.....some lines here
...
PLAYBOOK: install_tool.yml *******************************************
1 plays in install_tool.yml
Enter Company API URL:  [https://{{ instance }}.company.com]:
```

As using `when: ( "{{ install_tool }}" == "true" and ...)` condition within  `vars_prompt` section, under/for `- name: company_api_url` variable, it didn't error out for any syntax issues or etc (that means, Ansible doesn't think it's wrong), then **WHY**, Ansible is still prompting me to enter the above `vars_prompts` variable, even when I'm passing `--extra-vars "install_tool=false"` **--OR--** if I **uncomment** the line: `install_tool: false` under `vars:` section?

**PS:** `when: ...` condition is successfully working for the `pre_tasks` section i.e. when install_tool is true, it shows the value of those 2 variables and when install_tool is set to false, then it does NOT run the `- debug` step and skips it (which is expected).

Thanks.

Comment: Nail it down to one single question and present a reproducible example.

Comment: @ceving I changed my post, does that help? I thought to provide some explanation in detail. Does the above install_tool.yml work at your end for showing a substituted `default` value and is the prompt part skipped when `install_tool` is set to false?

Comment: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/19777

Comment: It doesn't look like `vars_prompt:` uses the `when:` directive at all... if you just add a simple `when: False` you can see that it is ignored.

Comment: @RobH You are right. I wonder if under pre_tasks, I can use some native module, prompt a user conditionally (in some cases typos etc to make sure things dont break at 98% of the run) and register the variable but I guess that's not going to work as command line variable will superceed all or is that possible. It would have been good to have this feature to make Ansible both interactive/non-interactive at least for Ansible INTERACTIVE runs. For non-interactive runs (if -e var=value is not correct), then it's OK for Ansible to fail if the passed value was incorrect for some reason (typo)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check all supported attributes for prompted vars [here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/9694d60af5e9cde7aa684e9795b79f9fbb928ce5/lib/ansible/executor/playbook_executor.py#L105).

`when` statement is not supported for prompted vars. And never was.

Templated default values for prompted vars is [not supported](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/11757) also.

The only way to prevent vars prompt is to pass the variable in question via extra_vars. In your example, if you pass `-e company_api_url=my_custom_url`, Ansible will skip prompting for it.

Comment: I agree Konstantin. It would be really nice to have conditional prompts i.e. if the passed value is not what the user desires (for ex: Typos/Values dependent upon time windows etc), then Ansible automation is intelligent enough to prompt a user at least for an interactive run. Is there any plan to add this feature/capability? I agree for a non-interactive run, we don't want Ansible to prompt a user in the middle of the run.

Comment: I'm not an Ansible team developer, so can't tell you about any plans, sorry :) But I'm advocate of least possible interactive behaviour. I use `assert` task at the beginning of many playbooks to make sure that all data that is required during further playbook run is present and give meaningful error message for user to fix input data.

Comment: Agree, I guess I should fail fast then in such cases.