# Ansible: Don't execute the vars_prompt for a specific tag in playbook?

Tags: ansible

I have this example `playbook.yaml`:

```
---
- name: Cluster Provisioning
  hosts: cluster
  become: true
  gather_facts: true
  roles:
    - role: cluster
  tags: cluster
  vars_prompt:
    - name: prompt_disk_trim
      prompt: Trim SSD disks? [Y/n]
      default: 'n'
      private: false
    - name: prompt_password
      prompt: Enter password
      unsafe: true
    - name: prompt_password_check
      prompt: Retype password
      unsafe: true

- name: Charts Provisioning
  hosts: server
  become: true
  gather_facts: true
  roles:
    - role: cilium
    - role: certmanager
  tags: charts
  vars_prompt: []
```

When I run the execution based on a specific tag, I get the prompt:

```
$ ansible-playbook --check --tags charts playbook.yaml
Trim SSD disks? [Y/n] [n]:
```

I tried adding an empty list for `vars_prompt` in second play, without success. My goal is not to execute the prompts, when I use the `charts` tag. Thank you for your help.

Edit: I already looked at `pause` but unfortunately I cannot use it because I'm also passing passwords. I updated the playbook to reflect that.

Comment: My understanding is there is no way to conditionally execute vars_prompt with a when or tags.  The only option as stated in the help is to define the variable with --extra-vars. Then the var_prompt will be skipped.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ansible to Conditionally Prompt for a Variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25466675/ansible-to-conditionally-prompt-for-a-variable)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use *when* condition only on roles, blocks, and tasks (including pre_tasks and post_tasks). See [Playbook Keywords](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html). You can't use it on a play. As a consequence, you can't execute *vars_prompt* conditionally.

Instead, you can use [pause](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/pause_module.html). Put it into the pre_tasks, run it once, and test the tags. See [ansible_run_tags](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#term-ansible_run_tags)

```yaml
  pre_tasks:
    - block:
        - pause:
            prompt: Trim SSD disks? [Y/n]
          register: out
        - set_fact:
            prompt_disk_trim: "{{ out.user_input }}"
      run_once: true
      when: "'charts' not in ansible_run_tags"
```

---

Notes:

- Optionally, use *tags* instead of the *when* condition, and
- Set the [default](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-filters.default) value

```yaml
  pre_tasks:
    - block:
        - pause:
            prompt: Trim SSD disks? [Y/n]
          register: out
        - set_fact:
            prompt_disk_trim: "{{ out.user_input|d('Y', true) }}"
      run_once: true
      tags: cluster
```

- Optionally, use the filter [password_hash](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#hashing-and-encrypting-strings-and-passwords), and
- Set [echo](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/pause_module.html#parameter-echo)=false to mask the input

```yaml
  pre_tasks:
    - block:
        - pause:
            prompt: Enter password
            echo: false
          register: out
        - set_fact:
            pswd: "{{ out.user_input|password_hash('sha256', 'mysecretsalt') }}"
      run_once: true
      tags: cluster
```

---

Given the below project for testing

```bash
shell> tree .
.
├── ansible.cfg
├── hosts
├── playbook.yaml
└── roles
    ├── cilium
    │   └── tasks
    │       └── main.yml
    └── cluster
        └── tasks
            └── main.yml
```

```ini
shell> cat hosts
[cluster]
server
host_A
host_B
```

```yaml
shell> cat roles/cilium/tasks/main.yml 
- debug:
    msg: cilium running ...

shell> cat roles/cluster/tasks/main.yml 
- debug:
    var: prompt_disk_trim
```

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml 
- hosts: cluster

  pre_tasks:
    - block:
        - pause:
            prompt: Trim SSD disks? [Y/n]
          register: out
        - set_fact:
            prompt_disk_trim: "{{ out.user_input }}"
      run_once: true
      when: "'charts' not in ansible_run_tags"

  roles:
    - role: cluster
  tags: cluster

- hosts: server

  roles:
    - role: cilium
  tags: charts
```

Without a tag, the first play asks for input and both roles work as expected

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml

PLAY [cluster] *******************************************************************************

TASK [pause] *********************************************************************************
[pause]
Trim SSD disks? [Y/n]:
ok: [server]

TASK [set_fact] ******************************************************************************
ok: [server]

TASK [cluster : debug] ***********************************************************************
ok: [server] => 
  prompt_disk_trim: Y
ok: [host_A] => 
  prompt_disk_trim: Y
ok: [host_B] => 
  prompt_disk_trim: Y

PLAY [server] ********************************************************************************

TASK [cilium : debug] ************************************************************************
ok: [server] => 
  msg: cilium running ...

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
host_A: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host_B: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
server: ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

When you select the tag *charts* both pre_tasks and roles are skipped in the first play

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml -t charts

PLAY [cluster] *******************************************************************************

PLAY [server] ********************************************************************************

TASK [cilium : debug] ************************************************************************
ok: [server] => 
  msg: cilium running ...

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
server: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Thank you Vladimir for taking the time to answer. Unfortunately, I cannot use `pause` because I also have to pass passwords, which are unsafe with Ansible `pause`. I missed this detail into OP, I will update my question

Comment: How is *vars_prompt* safer compared to *pause*?

Comment: `vars_prompt` allows to mask and hash the user input, `pause` does not.

Comment: I added an example of how to mask and hash the user input with *pause*.

Comment: Thank you for the updated details Vladimir, I accepted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I read [this part](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/643277b97681d26c3da974381298005c34054633/lib/ansible/executor/playbook_executor.py#L141) of Ansible source code correctly, there is no option to skip the `vars_prompt` other than specify the variables using `--extra-vars`.

A kludge workaround could be a little wrapper script that will run different playbooks based on the tags found in the parsed command, and one of them would import the other:

```yaml
--
- name: Cluster Provisioning
  hosts: cluster
  become: true
  gather_facts: true
  roles:
    - role: cluster
  tags: cluster
  vars_prompt:
    - name: prompt_disk_trim
      prompt: Trim SSD disks? [Y/n]
      default: 'n'
      private: false
    - name: prompt_password
      prompt: Enter password
      unsafe: true
    - name: prompt_password_check
      prompt: Retype password
      unsafe: true

- name: Charts Provisioning
  import_playbook: playbook.yml
  tags: charts
```